# How to use spécific User-Agent with (Magical) ExoPlayer in android?

Tags: java, android, user-agent, exoplayer

I'm using Android Studio and i need to add ExoPlayer in my app and i need to use a specific user-agent, so i found this MagicalExoPlayer :

https://github.com/HamidrezaAmz/MagicalExoPlayer

This "version" of ExoPlayer is very easy to use and in the readme we can see it's easy to put specific header. 
So i tried to put a specific user-agent like this :

```
HashMap<String , String> extraHeaders = new HashMap<>();
extraHeaders.put("User-Agent","My User Agent");
andExoPlayerView.setSource("STREAM_URL", extraHeaders);
```

But the user-agent don't change, i have the default user agent of ExoPlayer.

So how to use a specific user-agent with ExoPlayer ? (it's Better if i can use MagicalExoPlayer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The User Agent is provided to the Exoplayer while preparing the datasource for the player. Example:

```
DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,"MY_USER_AGENT");
```

Since MagicalExoPlayer is a wrapper over Exoplayer, it has set the field to a constant. See the [PublicValues.java class](https://github.com/HamidrezaAmz/MagicalExoPlayer/blob/f707f4563ffd25330abd71ebfecad07c2b61be63/library/src/main/java/com/potyvideo/library/utils/PublicValues.java) in the github repository. You can ask the author to expose a public setter to the field. Another way would be copy the library module to your project and change the value of User Agent in the `PublicValues` class. You'll need to change the build.gradle to compile the module. I would strongly advise to ask the author and not copy over the module unless it is necessary because you'll have to manually update the module afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, i already asked the author about the User-Agent : https://github.com/HamidrezaAmz/MagicalExoPlayer/issues/9 but still no reply, maybe i gonna use the original ExoPlayer it's probably the easiest way.